# How to count() and aggregate values without using group by?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having trouble obtaining data and categorizing it within a select without filtering it through the group by clause.

I have a table populated with the results of a customer satisfaction poll, which includes the office at which the client was served, the type of service he was provided, and the score given by the client.

I need to know the NPS scores and group them by business and office.
(ID column not included because I can barely fit it, but it's there)

| service | office | score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Rental | office 1 | 1 |
| New Cars | office 1 | 6 |
| New Cars | office 2 | 5 |
| Rental | office 2 | 10 |
| Rental | office 3 | 9 |
| New Cars | office 3 | 8 |

The thing is, I need to count the amount of scores between 0 and 6 (detractors), between 7 and 8 (passives), and 9 and 10 (promoters). So it becomes something like this:

| service | office | qty_detractors | qty_passives | qty_promoters | qty_answers | NPS_score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Rental | office 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |  |
| Rental | office 2 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |  |
| Rental | office 3 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |  |
| New Cars | office 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |  |
| New Cars | office 2 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 2 |  |
| New Cars | office 3 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 2 |  |

To calculate the nps_score = **(qty_promoters/qty_answers) - (qty_detractors /qty_answers)**

I thought of doing a count of scores to get the total amount of answers from every segment, but I don't know how to then spread the data according to my needs.

```
select 
    business,
    office,
    count(score) as total
from dbo.poll_results
group by business,
    office
```

I thought about making a temporary table in which I could store the id's of each answer and classify the results into the 3 categories.

```
select id, 
    score, 
    "type" = 
    case
        when score <= 6  then 'detractor'
        when score > 6 and score < 9 then 'passive'
        when score >= 9 then 'promoter'
        end
into #tmp_NPS_scores
from dbo.poll_results
```

And then joining the two, but I'm very confused about how this is going to turn out and so far I've been hitting walls trying to structure the query.

I've been investigating about `PIVOT()`, but I still don't quite get it I believe, tried playing with it but I only got errors in return. Should I pursue this as a solution?

I hope I could make the problem as understandable as possible, I'm working with over ten columns and I believe this is enough for anyone to comprehend.

Thank you in advance.

Oh and just in case anyone wonders, I know this can be done with BI tools, in fact I need to make a dashboard out of this in Tableau, but I was given the task to relieve some of the load off Tableau by making the NPS calculation inside the table.

Comment: Your output doesn't look right.  For example, shouldn't New Cars | Office 2 have 0 promoters?  That's not the only error.

Comment: Hi, thank you for pointing the errors, I think I fixed them. I'm having a terrible time trying to build these tables inside the question, someone downvoted my previous question because I posted snapshots of a table, and said I had to insert tables this way, which is horrible and leads a to a lot of problems like the ones you pointed out, as I built the input and output as I was writing the question. Anyway, you can understand what I mean, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with breakout as (
    select service, office,
        count(case when score between 0 and 6  then 1 end) as qty_detractors,
        count(case when score between 7 and 8  then 1 end) as qty_passives,
        count(case when score between 9 and 10 then 1 end) as qty_promoters,
        count(*) as qty_answers
    from dbo.poll_results
    group by service, office
)
select *, (qty_promoters - qty_detractors) / qty_answers as NPS_score
from breakout
```

This is going to be a lot more efficient than executing separate queries and combining them all via joins and then having to deal with nulls values where  there were zeroes...

Comment: Hi, I used your method and it works great! I just have one question, what does the "then 1" do inside the count? At first I thought it was a multiplier, or maybe a bit value for true or false, but when I change the number after then, nothing changes.

Comment: @Mats Since it's counting values the only thing that really matters is that it isn't null. Try changing to `sum()` and you'll see the difference though.

Answer (score 1):

You can try and use CTE - common table expressions, temporary results sets to separate the count query into 3 needed groups and then build all the results together.

This is a readable and straightforward solution.

```
;WITH detractors AS 
 ( 
   SELECT service, office, COUNT(score) as count
   FROM poll
   WHERE score <=6
   GROUP by service, office
),
passives AS 
 ( 
   SELECT service, office, COUNT(score) as count
   FROM poll
   WHERE score > 6 AND score <= 9
   GROUP by service, office
),
promoters AS 
 ( 
   SELECT service, office, COUNT(score) as count
   FROM poll
   WHERE score > 9
   GROUP by service, office
),
totals AS 
 ( 
   SELECT service, office, COUNT(score) as count
   FROM poll
   GROUP by service, office
),
SELECT p.service, p.office, pro.count as promoters, det.count as detractors, pas.count as passives, ((pro.count/tot.count) - (det.count /tot.count)) as nps_score
FROM poll p
LEFT JOIN promoters pro ON p.office = pro.office AND p.service = pro.service
LEFT JOIN passives pass ON p.office = pass.office AND p.service = pass.service
LEFT JOIN detractors det ON p.office = det.office AND p.service = det.service
LEFT JOIN totals tot ON p.office = tot.office AND p.service = tot.service
```

**UPD:** [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73000165/3125477) achieves the same less complicated, using the CTEs as well.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I didn't know about this, and I'm going to investigate further, just one question, though, can I append another group by clause at the end of the code you sent, or must each subselect contain all of the group criterias I need to use?

Comment: Sure! Treat CTEs as separate temp tables. However, pay attention, that since you use in this select fields from CTEs - they needs to be included in a `GROUP BY` clause. May be you will want to make this `SELECT` CTE as well.

Comment: Wow, that sounds like a powerful option! Could you please clarify what you mean by "make this SELECT CTE as well" please? I don't quite get what you mean there. And thank you again for the quick answer : )

Comment: Enclose the last query in parenthesis and give it an alias as well: 
```SQL  
...
summary as (SELECT p.service, p.office, pro.count as promoters, det.count as detractors, pas.count as passives, ((pro.count/tot.count) - (det.count /tot.count)) as nps_score
...)
SELECT some new query
```